# item for item in numpy.ndarray

Tags: python, typeerror, numpy-ndarray

I have a numpy.ndarray `Datasets` which in the debug window looks like `array([['13.234...`.  This array can have several million elements in it and I'm trying to filter it down and then randomise the order of the filtered data.

On the line `RandomRows = ReducedList[RandomIndicies]` I get the error `only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index`.  From what I can see the `ReducedList` I'm generating is coming out in a different format `[array(['13.234...` and I can't figure out how to change this.

This is the code I have...

```
SearchRadUpper1 = 10
SearchRadUpper2 = 15

ReducedList = [Item for Item in DataSets[:] if math.sqrt((((float(Item[0]))**2) + ((float(Item[1]))**2) + ((float(Item[2]))**2))) <= SearchRadUpper1 \
    or math.sqrt((((float(Item[0]))**2) + ((float(Item[1]))**2) + ((float(Item[2]))**2))) <= SearchRadUpper2]

RandomIndices = RandomGenerator.integers(
    low=0, high=len(ReducedList), size=Count)

RandomRows = ReducedList[RandomIndices]
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If want to filter your array, there is no need for iterating. You can instead try

```
SearchRadUpper1 = 10

idx = np.where((np.linalg.norm(DataSets, axis=1) <= SearchRadUpper1))
ReducedList = DataSets[idx]

Count = 100
random_idx = np.random.choice(range(len(ReducedList, Count)))
RandomRows = ReducedList[random_idx]
```

Also it seems like your criteria of `Item <= SearchRadUpper1 or Item <= SearchRadUpper2` is not necessary as the first statement is always true if the second is true.

Comment: How do I incorporate the mathematical operation into this as the filtering is not just a single axis of the array and a result of several axes?  The `SearchRadUpper1` & `SearchRadUpper2` are variables that can be adjusted and I'm just catching instances where they put the larger number in `SearchRadUpper1`.

Comment: You question don't really make sense to me. If you are asking how you can use more than one filtering, you can have as many as you want with `np.where((arr >= 0.4) &  (arr< 0.2) | (arr == 0)......)`. It seems like you are missing some knowledge on how to use numpy. Here is a great introduction https://www.w3schools.com/python/numpy/numpy_intro.asp

Comment: For each Item in `DataSets` I need to multiply the first 3 values together, if the result < SearchRad then that Item is to be included in `ReducedList`.

I've modified the code to the following and it now works as I want but it's just very very slow because I'm iterating through each line.  If I could filter by the same criteria that would hopefully speed it up significantly.
`Indicies = np.asarray([Item for Item in DataSets[:] if math.sqrt((((XNom1-float(Item[0]))**2) + ((YNom1-float(Item[1]))**2) + ((ZNom1-float(Item[2]))**2))) <= SearchRadUpper1 \
    or math.sqrt((((...`

Comment: In your original question, you are comparing the norm of each row to a threshold "SearchRadUpper". I encourage you to read the guide for numpy as it would benefit you a lot to know more about how to efficiently work with arrays. That part is out of the scope of answering questions here :)